# Faster Cholesky factorization of $diag(\mathbf{x}_{i}) \otimes \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have many positive integer vectors $\mathbf{x}_{i} \in \mathcal{N}^{d_1}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, a p.s.d. matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \Re^{d_2\times d_2}$ and a p.s.d. matrix $\mathbf{B} \in \Re^{d_1d_2\times d_1d_2}$. For every $\mathbf{x}_{i}$ I want to compute the following Cholesky factorization:

$chol\bigg(diag(\mathbf{x}_{i}) \otimes \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}\bigg)$

My $d_1$ and $d_2$ are not small and I have a large $n$ hence computing the above Cholesky factorization for all $x_{i}$ is really time-consuming.

Since the matrix inside `chol()` is very structured and the only thing that is varying is $x_i$, is there a more efficient way to compute all these factorizations?

The problem arises in my Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm from my Bayesian statistics project. And I feel this problem is quite commonly encountered especially in hierarchical Gaussian models. Hence it would be great if there is a much more efficient solution. Any advice will be helpful! Thanks ahead for your time.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that there is a shortcut and you must consider alternatives. Do you really need these Cholesky factorizations or are they means to an end, i.e. you want to solve linear systems? Do you need to solve these systems to the limit of machine precision or would an iterative solver be acceptable? Are you matrices dense or sparse? Finally, you have a problem which is embarrassingly parallel, so it would be easy spread the problem across multiple computers.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for your advice. I need that Cholesky factorization since I need to sample from a multivariate Gaussian and what is inside is the covariance matrix of that Gaussian. And the matrix `B` is dense. And you are right, this is embarrassingly parallel. If there is no better solution then I will just parallel my code and run it on clusters.